# Pytorch model issues while running for multilabel classifications

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data, multilabel-classification

I am working on a classification problem using (1D-CNN) the model I built and the data loaders are working perfectly. However, during the training and the validation loops I encounter an issue.
I have a multilabel classification problem and before training the model on all 4 labels I have, I did a splitting and encoding for the label data so that each label will trained individually. the code below shows the splitting and the encoding steps are shown in the first 12 lines in the for loop below.

executing the code above within the training loop did the job for me. However, when I move onto the training functions, the model will train the outputs to match the first label group only, and when I observe the values of the output for the second, third and fourth run, the values are the same. the code below shows the training step: (the code below is included in the for loop mentioned above):

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(50)):
    
    for batch, (features, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        #encoding the labels
        Ordinal_Labels = encoder.fit_transform(labels)
        y1 = torch.from_numpy(Ordinal_Labels)
        y2 = y1.to(torch.int64)
        y_train = functional.one_hot(y2)
        x1 = y_train[:, 0:1, :]
        x2 = y_train[:, 1:2, :]
        x3 = y_train[:, 2:3, :]
        x4 = y_train[:, 3:4, :]
        label1 = torch.squeeze(x1, 1).to(torch.float64)
        label2 = torch.squeeze(x2, 1).to(torch.float64)
        label3 = torch.squeeze(x3, 1).to(torch.float64)
        label4 = torch.squeeze(x4, 1).to(torch.float64)
           
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
        #training the model 
        output1= model(features)
        output2= model(features)
        output3= model(features)
        output4= model(features)

        #obtaining the loss for each label 
        loss1= criterion(output1, label1)
        loss2= criterion(output2, label2)
        loss3= criterion(output3, label3)
        loss4= criterion(output4, label4)
    
        #backward pass tp update the model parameters 
        loss1.backward()
        loss2.backward()
        loss3.backward()
        loss4.backward()
        #updating the grad parameters after the backward propagation
        optimizer.step()

        #obtaining the total loss value
        loss= loss4 #+ loss2 + loss3 + loss4
    
        epoch_loss.append(loss.item())
```

I tried building separate functions for each label on which the model will be executed on a one label group, however, running all 4 function together in the same for loop gives the same error.

Any help in such a problem is much appreciated